# iOS how to programmatically draw "blue dot" with uncertainty radius, like iOS7 maps app?

Tags: ios, navigation, drawing, mapkit

I'm trying to create a view which looks similar to the "blue dot" in the maps app. Adding the center dot is easy, but I'm interested in **how I can add a "uncertainty" radius with inner/outer glow around the blue dot?**

[image]

```
 if(self.blueDot == nil)
    {
        self.blueDot = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,30,30)];
        self.blueDot.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
        self.blueDot.layer.cornerRadius = self.blueDot.bounds.size.width/2.0;

        self.blueDot.layer.borderColor =[UIColor whiteColor].CGColor;
        self.blueDot.layer.borderWidth = 4;
        self.blueDot.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
    }


    if(self.blueDot.superview == nil)
    {
        [self.mapImitationView addSubview:self.blueDot];
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've done this in some open source code which might be useful. But first, it's not clear in your question which element you are talking about. There is:

1. The user location dot (I call it `userLocation`). The blue & white dot in your image.
2. The indicator of GPS accuracy (I call it `accuracyCircleAnnotation`). You don't have this in your image.
3. The pulsing indicator, which shows once the accuracy is high enough to help highlight the user (I call it `trackingHaloAnnotation`). This is the blue & white halo in your image, however that image is from iOS 6 and prior.

You can see all of these in the `RMMapView` class, complete with animations, here in particular:

- Accuracy circle: https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-ios-sdk/blob/b83fc2ddf400b9e308fe0ccf87371f32b240d045/MapView/Map/RMMapView.m#L3473-L3489
- Tracking halo: https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-ios-sdk/blob/b83fc2ddf400b9e308fe0ccf87371f32b240d045/MapView/Map/RMMapView.m#L3521-L3570

Only note here is due to the framework it was built in, it was done with `CALayer` instead of directly with `UIView`.

You can find the resources that Apple uses here, extracted from MapKit with [iOS-Artwork-Extractor](https://github.com/0xced/iOS-Artwork-Extractor):

https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-ios-sdk/tree/release/MapView/Map/Resources

Hope this helps.